# Caching Bitmap bug at developer.android.com

Tags: java, android

I was just reading tutorial of caching bitmaps from url at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

refering to code

```
    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        // Get memory class of this device, exceeding this amount will throw an
        // OutOfMemory exception.
        final int memClass = ((ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(
                Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();

        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        final int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 8;

        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                // The cache size will be measured in bytes rather than number of items.
                return bitmap.getByteCount();
            }
        };
        ...
    }

    public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
            mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
        return mMemoryCache.get(key);
    }

public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    final String imageKey = String.valueOf(resId);

    final Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(imageKey);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_placeholder);
        BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(mImageView);
        task.execute(resId);
    }
}
```

in activity cache is beign initialize and there are two methods

1. **`addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap)`**
2. **`getBitmapFromMemCache(String key)`**

here is the BitmapWorkerTask class

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    ...
    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        final Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                getResources(), params[0], 100, 100));
        addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(params[0]), bitmap);
        return bitmap;
    }
    ...
}
```

now my question is that in **BitmapWorkerTask** class how come method **addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(params[0]), bitmap);** is called with having any reference to the methods that are defined in Activty or might be in some other Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BitmapWorkerTask is probably an inner class within the activity, thus providing it access to the defined methods.

Comment: right now i got developers.android they probably likes inner classes :)

Comment: Although its a very nice tutorial,nice and short way of Caching bimaps and through this you can easily implement **Lazy List Loading**.i have read many other tutorials they are quite lenghty and time wasting,i have implemented this in my code and works great

Comment: I get semantic errors when declaring BitmapWorkerTask as an inner class. Java compiler complains about the static methods in the inner class.

If I make the inner class static, then once again addBitmapToMemoryCache() is not accessible.
    "The method calculateInSampleSize cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type"

Answer (score 0):

For someone who still couldn't get the sample code work,

In order to get the code working, you should make BitmapWorkerTask class an inner class and then change its two static functions

```
public  static int calculateInSampleSize()
public  static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource()
```

to normal (non static) methods